# How to run springboot application without elasticsearch server running?

Tags: java, spring-boot, elasticsearch

I am using Springboot with MongoDb and Elasticsearch for my project. When my Elasticsearch server is running then my Springboot application is working fine but when the Elasticsearch server is stopped, my Springboot application also fails to start. According to my project's requirements, our Springboot application should still be running even though the Elasticsearch server fails to start as the majority of our APIs are built on Springboot and MongoDb and only a few depend on Elasticsearch. Is there any way I can achieve this?

**Elasticsearch configuration**

```
@Bean(destroyMethod = "close")
public RestHighLevelClient client() {

    RestHighLevelClient client = new RestHighLevelClient(
            RestClient.builder(new HttpHost(hostname, port,scheme))
                    .setRequestConfigCallback(
            new RestClientBuilder.RequestConfigCallback() {
                @Override
                public RequestConfig.Builder customizeRequestConfig(
                        RequestConfig.Builder requestConfigBuilder) {
                    return requestConfigBuilder
                            .setConnectTimeout(6000000)
                            .setSocketTimeout(6000000);
                }
            }));
    return client;
}
```

**Exception stack trace** (hidden some text for security)

```
Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2022-04-05 11:11:06.056 ERROR 9356 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed

org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name '-----': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field '-----'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name '-----': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field '-----'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name '-----' defined in ----- defined in @EnableElasticsearchRepositories declared on ElasticsearchRepositoriesRegistrar.EnableElasticsearchRepositoriesConfiguration: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.repository.support.SimpleElasticsearchRepository]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.dao.DataAccessResourceFailureException: Connection refused; nested exception is java.lang.RuntimeException: Connection refused
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.resolveFieldValue(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:660) ~[spring-beans-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:640) ~[spring-beans-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:119) ~[spring-beans-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessProperties(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:399) ~[spring-beans-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1413) ~[spring-beans-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:601) ~[spring-beans-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:524) ~[spring-beans-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335) ~[spring-beans-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333) ~[spring-beans-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208) ~[spring-beans-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:944) ~[spring-beans-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:918) ~[spring-context-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:583) ~[spring-context-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:145) ~[spring-boot-2.5.4.jar:2.5.4]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:754) ~[spring-boot-2.5.4.jar:2.5.4]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:434) ~[spring-boot-2.5.4.jar:2.5.4]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:338) ~[spring-boot-2.5.4.jar:2.5.4]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1343) ~[spring-boot-2.5.4.jar:2.5.4]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1332) ~[spring-boot-2.5.4.jar:2.5.4]
    at com.extramarks.questionMSA.MsaQuestionApplication.main(MsaQuestionApplication.java:24) ~[main/:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:49) ~[spring-boot-devtools-2.5.4.jar:2.5.4]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name '-----': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field '-----'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name '-----' defined in ----- defined in @EnableElasticsearchRepositories declared on ElasticsearchRepositoriesRegistrar.EnableElasticsearchRepositoriesConfiguration: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.repository.support.SimpleElasticsearchRepository]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.dao.DataAccessResourceFailureException: Connection refused; nested exception is java.lang.RuntimeException: Connection refused
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.resolveFieldValue(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:660) ~[spring-beans-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:640) ~[spring-beans-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:119) ~[spring-beans-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessProperties(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:399) ~[spring-beans-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1413) ~[spring-beans-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:601) ~[spring-beans-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:524) ~[spring-beans-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335) ~[spring-beans-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333) ~[spring-beans-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208) ~[spring-beans-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:276) ~[spring-beans-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1380) ~[spring-beans-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1300) ~[spring-beans-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.resolveFieldValue(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:657) ~[spring-beans-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
    ... 25 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name '-----' defined in ----- defined in @EnableElasticsearchRepositories declared on ElasticsearchRepositoriesRegistrar.EnableElasticsearchRepositoriesConfiguration: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.repository.support.SimpleElasticsearchRepository]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.dao.DataAccessResourceFailureException: Connection refused; nested exception is java.lang.RuntimeException: Connection refused
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1786) ~[spring-beans-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:602) ~[spring-beans-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:524) ~[spring-beans-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335) ~[spring-beans-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333) ~[spring-beans-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208) ~[spring-beans-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:276) ~[spring-beans-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1380) ~[spring-beans-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1300) ~[spring-beans-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.resolveFieldValue(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:657) ~[spring-beans-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
    ... 39 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.repository.support.SimpleElasticsearchRepository]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.dao.DataAccessResourceFailureException: Connection refused; nested exception is java.lang.RuntimeException: Connection refused
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:221) ~[spring-beans-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport.lambda$getTargetRepositoryViaReflection$5(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:543) ~[spring-data-commons-2.5.4.jar:2.5.4]
    at java.base/java.util.Optional.map(Optional.java:265) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport.getTargetRepositoryViaReflection(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:543) ~[spring-data-commons-2.5.4.jar:2.5.4]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport.getTargetRepositoryViaReflection(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:528) ~[spring-data-commons-2.5.4.jar:2.5.4]
    at org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.repository.support.ElasticsearchRepositoryFactory.getTargetRepository(ElasticsearchRepositoryFactory.java:74) ~[spring-data-elasticsearch-4.2.4.jar:4.2.4]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport.getRepository(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:319) ~[spring-data-commons-2.5.4.jar:2.5.4]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.lambda$afterPropertiesSet$5(RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.java:323) ~[spring-data-commons-2.5.4.jar:2.5.4]
    at org.springframework.data.util.Lazy.getNullable(Lazy.java:230) ~[spring-data-commons-2.5.4.jar:2.5.4]
    at org.springframework.data.util.Lazy.get(Lazy.java:114) ~[spring-data-commons-2.5.4.jar:2.5.4]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.afterPropertiesSet(RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.java:329) ~[spring-data-commons-2.5.4.jar:2.5.4]
    at org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.repository.support.ElasticsearchRepositoryFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(ElasticsearchRepositoryFactoryBean.java:69) ~[spring-data-elasticsearch-4.2.4.jar:4.2.4]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1845) ~[spring-beans-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1782) ~[spring-beans-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
    ... 49 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.dao.DataAccessResourceFailureException: Connection refused; nested exception is java.lang.RuntimeException: Connection refused
    at org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.core.ElasticsearchExceptionTranslator.translateExceptionIfPossible(ElasticsearchExceptionTranslator.java:75) ~[spring-data-elasticsearch-4.2.4.jar:4.2.4]
    at org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.core.ElasticsearchRestTemplate.translateException(ElasticsearchRestTemplate.java:402) ~[spring-data-elasticsearch-4.2.4.jar:4.2.4]
    at org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.core.ElasticsearchRestTemplate.execute(ElasticsearchRestTemplate.java:385) ~[spring-data-elasticsearch-4.2.4.jar:4.2.4]
    at org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.core.DefaultIndexOperations.doExists(DefaultIndexOperations.java:107) ~[spring-data-elasticsearch-4.2.4.jar:4.2.4]
    at org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.core.AbstractDefaultIndexOperations.exists(AbstractDefaultIndexOperations.java:141) ~[spring-data-elasticsearch-4.2.4.jar:4.2.4]
    at org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.repository.support.SimpleElasticsearchRepository.(SimpleElasticsearchRepository.java:93) ~[spring-data-elasticsearch-4.2.4.jar:4.2.4]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:490) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:208) ~[spring-beans-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
    ... 62 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Connection refused
    at org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.core.ElasticsearchRestTemplate.translateException(ElasticsearchRestTemplate.java:400) ~[spring-data-elasticsearch-4.2.4.jar:4.2.4]
    ... 71 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
    at org.elasticsearch.client.RestClient.extractAndWrapCause(RestClient.java:880) ~[elasticsearch-rest-client-7.12.1.jar:7.12.1]
    at org.elasticsearch.client.RestClient.performRequest(RestClient.java:283) ~[elasticsearch-rest-client-7.12.1.jar:7.12.1]
    at org.elasticsearch.client.RestClient.performRequest(RestClient.java:270) ~[elasticsearch-rest-client-7.12.1.jar:7.12.1]
    at org.elasticsearch.client.RestHighLevelClient.internalPerformRequest(RestHighLevelClient.java:1654) ~[elasticsearch-rest-high-level-client-7.12.1.jar:7.12.1]
    at org.elasticsearch.client.RestHighLevelClient.performRequest(RestHighLevelClient.java:1639) ~[elasticsearch-rest-high-level-client-7.12.1.jar:7.12.1]
    at org.elasticsearch.client.IndicesClient.exists(IndicesClient.java:963) ~[elasticsearch-rest-high-level-client-7.12.1.jar:7.12.1]
    at org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.core.DefaultIndexOperations.lambda$doExists$2(DefaultIndexOperations.java:107) ~[spring-data-elasticsearch-4.2.4.jar:4.2.4]
    at org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.core.ElasticsearchRestTemplate.execute(ElasticsearchRestTemplate.java:383) ~[spring-data-elasticsearch-4.2.4.jar:4.2.4]
    ... 70 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.checkConnect(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.finishConnect(SocketChannelImpl.java:777) ~[na:na]
    at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.DefaultConnectingIOReactor.processEvent(DefaultConnectingIOReactor.java:174) ~[httpcore-nio-4.4.14.jar:4.4.14]
    at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.DefaultConnectingIOReactor.processEvents(DefaultConnectingIOReactor.java:148) ~[httpcore-nio-4.4.14.jar:4.4.14]
    at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.AbstractMultiworkerIOReactor.execute(AbstractMultiworkerIOReactor.java:351) ~[httpcore-nio-4.4.14.jar:4.4.14]
    at org.apache.http.impl.nio.conn.PoolingNHttpClientConnectionManager.execute(PoolingNHttpClientConnectionManager.java:221) ~[httpasyncclient-4.1.4.jar:4.1.4]
    at org.apache.http.impl.nio.client.CloseableHttpAsyncClientBase$1.run(CloseableHttpAsyncClientBase.java:64) ~[httpasyncclient-4.1.4.jar:4.1.4]
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829) ~[na:na]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can mark them beans with @Lazy so spring will not construct them on application startup. It will construct them when you use them runtime.

please see this documentation

https://memorynotfound.com/lazy-initialize-autowired-dependencies-with-lazy-annotation/

Comment: Adding @Lazy above my ElasticsearchRepository and above all the places I have Autowired it fixed the problem.